# Scroll view for multiple textFields wont work

Tags: uiscrollview, uitextfield

Hi i can get scroll to work with one text box quite easily, however when i add 10 text boxes, and use code from apples documentation i cant figure out how to get it to delegate the touch of any of the 10 fields to scroll the view, i cant work out how to connect activeField to the textField in question.  i think thats where im falling down, and the answer lies in delegation

```
@interface ImmyViewController ()

@end

@implementation ImmyViewController
@synthesize activeField;
@synthesize scrollView;
@synthesize text1;
@synthesize text2;
@synthesize text3;
@synthesize text4; 
@synthesize text5;
@synthesize text6;
@synthesize text7;
@synthesize text8;
@synthesize text9;
@synthesize text10;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    text1.delegate =self;
    text2.delegate =self;
    text3.delegate =self;
    text4.delegate =self;
    text5.delegate =self;
    text6.delegate =self;
    text7.delegate =self;
    text8.delegate =self;
    text9.delegate =self;
    activeField.delegate=self;

    text10.delegate =self;

// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//---set the viewable frame of the scroll view---
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);

//---set the content size of the scroll view---
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 833)];

}
```

// Call this method somewhere in your view controller setup code.
    - (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
    {
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self                                               selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                    name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardDidShowNotification is sent.
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

```
UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;

// If active text field is hidden by keyboard, scroll it so it's visible
// Your application might not need or want this behavior.
CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) ) {
    CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, text10.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
    [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
}
```

}

// Called when the UIKeyboardWillHideNotification is sent
    - (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
    {

```
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
 }

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can manage all the textfields by using textFieldDidBeginEditing begin simply replace your values in this code.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField.tag==1) {
        [scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0)animated:YES];
    }
    if (textField.tag==2) {
        [scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 81)animated:YES]; 
    }
    if (textField.tag ==3) {
        [scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 115)animated:YES]; 
    }
    if (textField.tag ==4) {
        [scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 150)animated:YES]; 
    }
    if (textField.tag ==5) {
        [scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 185)animated:YES]; 
    }
    if (textField.tag ==6) {
        [scroll_view setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 220)animated:YES]; 
    }

}
```

Comment: each text boxed required a tag to correspond with the tag property mentioned, but this code word work with some minor adjustment to the cgpointmake value so it scrolled upwards the right amount on the 10th textField which isnt mentioned here, thanks i apreciate the help

Comment: Yes Ofcorse i meansioned that replace your values in above code.